# Flask_SQLAlchemy Reading a New DataBase

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use Flask_SQLAlchemy to map an **External Database** beside the one I have in my `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']`

where the **External Database** is a User Input so there's no way i can guess the Database structure for each user

I've allowed the connection between the **user's database** and **my system** by

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    engine = db.create_engine(USER_DB)
    Session = db.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = db.scoped_session(engine) 

#after that i was able to get the table name's and structure using 

    x = {table:db.Table(table,db.metadata,autoload=True,autoload_with=engine)
                 for table in engine.table_names()}
    print(f'\n\n x  = {x} \n\n')
    findme = session.query(test1.filter_by(id=1).first())
```

**console :**

```
x = {'test1': Table('test1', MetaData(bind=None), Column('id', INTEGER(), table=<test1>, nullable=False, server_default=DefaultClause(<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.TextClause object at 0x000001F83BCAEC50>, for_update=False)), Column('name', VARCHAR(), table=<test1>, nullable=False), schema=None), 'test2': Table('test2', MetaData(bind=None), Column('id2', INTEGER(), table=<test2>, nullable=False, server_default=DefaultClause(<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.TextClause object at 0x000001F83BCCEA58>, for_update=False)), Column('name2', VARCHAR(length=200), table=<test2>, nullable=False), schema=None)}
```

you can see it can read the Structure of the columns there

then the rest of the output :

**( Trace Back )**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "D:\app1\app.py", line 181, in test
    cc = session.query(test1.filter_by(id=1).first())
NameError: name 'test1' is not defined
```

how to allow **SQLALCHEMY**  to **define the Structure automatically** ? Are any of those

***Automap / reflect / python package "sqlacodegen" *** useful in this  situation and if yes how I can benefit from it  ?

Comment: SQLAlchemy does this via [reflection](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/reflection.html).

Comment: @PGHE that is great , do you think i should use sqlalchemy instead of FLask_SqlALchemy ?

Comment: If you're making a Flask app then Flask_SQLAlchemy can help. It's just an extension to make working with Flask and SQLalchemy easier. You can still reflect all the tables with `db.reflect(app=app)`, [see the API](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/) .